# How to add a package in overleaf

Tags: packages, overleaf

I was asked to use the following format for my report **in Overleaf**

Please use the following set-up within LaTeX:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[y4project]{edmaths}
```

You can download the style file here:
https://info.maths.ed.ac.uk/assets/files/Projects/edmaths.sty

This is a .sty file,I am not sure how to implement it.

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Error looks like this

[image]

Comment: Upload it to overleaf in the same folder your main tex file is.

Comment: I've uploaded it, but there was an compile error

Comment: I can only guess that the error is a file that ends without anything. You don't have a document environment.

Comment: As @Johannes_B says, your main.tex is incomplete: you need at least `\begin{document}Hello World!\end{document}` after those two lines. You may have to refer to your instructor's guidelines about how to use the package to write your report.