# Playing cards symbols using Overleaf

Tags: packages, cards

While writing a paper about a card game I come across [An experimental LaTeX Poker Package](http://web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker-doc.pdf), which allows cards symbols.  It looks perfect for my needs.

However when adding `\usepackage{poker}` I get the following error:

> LaTeX Error: File `poker.sty' not found.  The compiler cannot find the
>   file you want to include. Make sure that you have uploaded the file
>   and specified the file location correctly.

### A follow-up question:

After following your advices, I placed `pst-poker.sty` in the Overleaf folder and used `\usepackage{pst-poker}`, however, when I write 
`\Qh`, `\Ks`, `\fiveh`, `\ninec` I get [image]

#### Solved:

As stated at [Getting `pst-poker` to work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420242/getting-pst-poker-to-work), I had to change Overleaf's compiler to **XeLaTeX**, this is done at: Menu > Settings > Compiler.

#### Note: ArXiv do not accept XeLaTeX-compile-papers.  I had to remove that package and change to a pdfLatex compiler before submitting to arXiv.

[image]

Comment: Try download this and upload it on your project: http://web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker.sty

Comment: Note that there is a later package called [`pst-poker`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-poker) which is based on the package you found, and this newer package is on CTAN.

Comment: Can you post the full code that gives you this? Then I can try what comes out on my my PC.

Comment: Sounds a bit as if you only copied the `sty`-file, but not the auxiliary files (images) as suggested by @Marjin's comment under my answer. But wihtout a MWE it's  hard to tell for us. If the follow-up question begins to evolve into it's own question, please consider opening a new question.

Comment: Also, do you get any error messages, or does it compile fine?

Comment: I stand corrected. Your follow-up question is a duplicate of this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420242/getting-pst-poker-to-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overleaf uses TeX Live 2016 (https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/What_packages_do_you_support%3F). The `poker` package is not part of TeX Live 2016

But you can upload any packages to overleaf as part of your project ([How to add a package in overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414780/how-to-add-a-package-in-overleaf?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

For this you'd need to download the`.sty`-file as suggested by @koleygr, from web.mit.edu/foley/games/Arcadia/sr/poker/poker.sty and place it in the right folder in your Overleaf project

Comment: It looks like they are upgrading: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/477874/problem-with-dotstyle?noredirect=1#comment1207256_477874

Comment: Good to know. Though this is not going to affect the (non-)availability of `poker.sty`. Is it?

Comment: Probably not, as neither TeXLive 2018 has it. However it looks like [`pst-poker`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-poker) was introduced in 2017 :) (oh, Marijn just said that :)

Comment: Note that `poker.sty` loads some images for the playing cards, so you need those files as well. You can probably get those images from `pst-poker`, and use them with `poker.sty`, since the `pst-poker` is based on `poker.sty`.